# discord.js unlimited purge command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, purge

Is there a way to make this better? I'm trying to make unlimited purge command... But it seems like message.channel.messages.cache only gets message the time you used it and I don't really know how to make it better. The bot will just lag for a long time... and cycle wont break because of that.

```js
    for (let i = 1; i <= amount/100; i++) {
           let messagecount = message.channel.messages.cache.size
           if(messagecount<=5){ 
              console.log("break")
                break}
           message.channel.bulkDelete(100)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Whats exactly is your questions?

Comment: how to delete more than 100 messages at once in discord

Comment: You are being ratelimited by Discord API. There's a reason why you can't bulk delete more than 100. Your method is considered API spam and could get you and your bot banned from accessing the API

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Discord API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#bulk-delete-messages), you can't delete messages older than 2 weeks through the Discord API, and neither can you with more than 100 messages. This is not a limitation you should/would want to break, and you may encounter [the risk of being ratelimited](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#exceeding-a-rate-limit). Of course, you could loop this, as you tried, but the ratelimit is still here. If I were you and wanted to delete the messages this bad, I would either call the command multiple times, or loop the `bulkDelete` with a cooldown (2000ms would be enough, I guess?).

Comment: I already knew that and there's a way to delete more than 100 messages... The code I gave does that but lags out. SO yeah your answer doesnt help at all but thanks for trying

Comment: Oh, yes there's a way: but in a single request, you can't delete more than 100 messages at a time. You can still try to loop it though.

Comment: This is not an answer, you are just spoonfeeding the OP which will not help them in the long run.

Comment: In fact this is an answer. Regardless of the correctness of the answer or whether it spoonfeeds the OP or not, from the point of view of the Low Quality Posts review queue (where I came across this answer) this is an attempt to answer the question so should not be flagged as either 'Not An Answer' or 'Very Low Quality'. Ask yourself if it's conceivable that the OP could accept the answer. If it is, it's likely that an NAA or VLQ flag will be declined. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27938779).

Comment: @Elitezen I recognize this is not a high-quality answer, but I think it remains one in my view. The question is: how can I do X? And my answer is: No, you can't do X. I added the code because I didn't completely understand the question at first. However, I stand my point by saying that yes, you *can* delete more than 100 messages with some kind of loop and a cooldown. Anything is possible, you just need to find the right way to do it --of course, spamming the API isn't something I'd recommend.

Comment: I edited my post, I tried to be more accurate.